# Eigenvalues of projection matrix proof

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The assertion is as follows:"If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix A for which $A = A^2$ then $\lambda = 0 $ or $ \lambda = 1$. Prove if true or use a counter example.

My intuition is to first find a matrix A that satisfies the constraint:
$$
A = AA \\
A^{-1}A = A^{-1}AA \\
I = A 
$$

I solved for the eigenvalues and found that $\lambda = 1$, however I am not sure how to end off the proof by showing that $\lambda = 0$ is also an eigenvalue. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But is $A$ invertible?

Comment: FYI, I changed "identity matrix" to "[projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) matrix" in the subject, because $A^2 = A$ is the defining property of a projection matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be an eigenvector associated with $\lambda$, then one has:
$$Ax=\lambda x\tag{1}.$$
Multiplying this equality by $A$ leads to:
$$A^2x=\lambda Ax.$$
But since $A^2=A$ and $Ax=\lambda x$, one has:
$$Ax=\lambda^2x\tag{2}.$$
According to $(1)$ and $(2)$, one gets:
$$(\lambda^2-\lambda)x=0.$$
Whence the result, since $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be an Eigenvector associated to $\lambda$.

$$Av=\lambda v$$

and

$$AAv=\lambda^2v=Av=\lambda v$$

so that $$\lambda^2=\lambda.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to prove this is to use the fact that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$. So take $f(x) = x^2 - x$. Then we have that $\lambda^2 - \lambda$ is an eignevalue of $f(A) = A^2 - A = 0$. But all eigenvalues of the zero matrix are $0$, hence we must have $\lambda^2 - \lambda = 0$, i.e. $\lambda = 1$ or $0$