# Describe the set of all possible real projector matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices

So I started answering my own question as I went but there was a lot of tedious work (for me), and I couldn't find a list of projector matrices, so I figured I would leave this up for posterity. But please let me know if I missed any matrices or if there's an easier way of building the set (and of course if there's any errors). I posted my results as an answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look for all rank $1$ projectors, because rank $0$ and rank $2$ are obvious.

If $P$ is such a projector, then its characteristic polynomial is $X^2-X$. In particular, $\det P=0$ and $\operatorname{trace}P=1$. Thus the matrix must have the form
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & 1-a \end{bmatrix}
$$
If we square it, we get
$$
P^2=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+bc & b \\
c & bc+(1-a)^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the relations become
$$
\begin{cases}
a(1-a)-bc = 0 \\[4px]
a^2+bc=a \\[4px]
bc+(1-a)^2=1-a
\end{cases}
$$
which however are equivalent to one another. Thus the condition is just
$$
bc=a-a^2
$$

Actually, the check about $P$ being idempotent is not necessary. The condition that the trace is $1$ is satisfied and $\det P=0$ implies $bc=a-a^2$. Now the characteristic polynomial is $X^2-X$ and Hamilton-Cayley provides $P^2=P$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by characteristic polynomial here "If $P$ is such a projector, then its characteristic polynomial is $X^2-X$. In particular, $\det P=0$ and $\operatorname{trace}P=1$."

Comment: @Zduff The eigenvalues of a rank $1$ projector are $0$ and $1$, so the characteristic polynomial $X^2-\operatorname{trace}(P)X+\det(P)$ must have $0$ and $1$ as roots.

Comment: Got it. Thought you were using a matrix $X$ at first.

Comment: Okay, I finally understood it. Thank you. I'm not sure but I don't think you need to square your matrix in the second part since you've already used the fact that $P$ is a projector to determine det$(P) =0$ then we can just go from $\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & 1-a \end{array} \right)$ to get $ a-a^2 = bc $

Comment: @Zduff Yes, that's right, but only invoking Hamilton-Cayley.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

consider that a projector has the eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ ( you can see: [Eigenvalues of projection matrix proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411476/eigenvalues-of-projection-matrix-proof)). So any projector is represented by a matrix similar to a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1$ and $0$.

Comment: Isn’t the identity map also a projector?

Comment: One could also describe this as the set of all singular matrices with trace equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if $P \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ is a projector matrix then

$$P^2 = P$$

and writing $P$ as

$$P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right)$$

we could solve the system from $P(P - I) = 0$

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}a-1 & b\\c & d-1\end{array}\right) = 0$$

In which case we get the system of equations

$$ \begin{array}  
aa(a-1) + bc = 0 \\ 
ab + b(d-1) = 0 \\ 
c(a-1) + dc = 0 \\ 
bc + d(d-1) = 0
\end{array} \quad \to \quad
\begin{array}   
aa^2- a + bc = 0 \\ 
ab + bd - b = 0 \\ 
ac - c + dc = 0 \\ 
bc + d^2 - d = 0
\end{array}   
$$

Subtracting the last equation from the first we get

$$a^2 - d^2 = a - d \implies (a-d)(a+d) = a-d \implies a =d \quad \text{or} \quad a = 1-d$$

---

**Case 1:** $a = 1-d$

Plugging into equation 2 we get

$$  
(1-d)b + b(d-1) = 0
 $$

Which implies equation 2 is satisfied for all $b$. Plugging into equation 3 we get a similar result for $c$. But multiplying equations 2 and 3 we get a common factor of $bc$, yet the product $eqn. 1 \times eqn. 2$ needs to equal zero. This implies $bc = 0$ (note the remaining factor has no solution which means $bc = 0$ is the only way to satisfy the system). So now, if $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary subject to their product equaling zero we get (eqn 1)

$$   
a(a-1) = 0  
\implies \boxed{a = 0,1} \implies \boxed{d = 1,0} \quad \text{respectively}
$$

our solution set in this case is

$$  
P_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & b\\c & 0\end{array}\right)  \quad \text{and}  
\quad 
P_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & b\\c & 1\end{array}\right)\,,  \quad 
\text{for all} \, \, b\cdot c = 0
$$

that is, either $b$ or $c$ has to be zero.

For example, $P_2$ with $b = 0$, multiplied by a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ scales the $x$ component by factor $c$, adds the result $xc$ to the $y$ component of the vector, and maps the result to the $y$-axis. Here's what it looks like in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ehcwrmdttr). Note that $P_2$ becomes an orthogonal projector when $c = 0$.

[Here's what the $P_1$ set looks like in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rw8swnxdd0) (note that the projector is orthogonal when $c = 0$).

---

**Case 2:** $ a = d$

Applied to equation 3

$$c(d-1) + dc = 0 \implies c(2d-1) = 0 \implies c = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad 
d = \frac{1}{2}$$

Inspecting equation 1 we see that for $c = 0$ we have

$$a(a-1) = 0 \tag{$\star$}$$

A quick analysis of $(\star)$: $a = d = c = 0 \implies b = 0$ which is the trivial case of the zero matrix. If $a = d = 1$ then equation 2 implies $b = 0 = c$ which is the other trivial case of the identity matrix. Done with $(\star)$.

But nontrivially, for $d = 1/2$ we find via elementary algebra that our only restriction is that $bc = 1/4$. That is

$$  
P_3 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1/2 & b\\c & 1/2\end{array}\right) \quad bc = 1/4 
$$

[It projects onto hyperbolas it looks like, but I'm not sure how to make it work.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jylxk8kzva)

---

**Summary:** The only 2D real projector matrices are the identity matrix, the zero matrix, and the sets

$$  
P_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & b\\c & 0\end{array}\right)\, ,  
\quad 
P_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & b\\c & 1\end{array}\right)\,,  \quad 
\text{for all} \, \, bc = 0\, , \\ \text{and}  \quad  
P_3 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1/2 & b\\c & 1/2\end{array}\right) \quad bc = 1/4 
$$

Comment: As far as I can see, if $P=\begin{bmatrix}9/25 & 12/25 \\ 12/25 & 16/25\end{bmatrix}$, then $P^2=P$. But this matrix doesn't appear in your classification.

Comment: @egreg Very true.

Comment: Case 2: The image of a linear transformation on $\mathbb R^2$ is either a point (the zero vector), a line, or the entire space. “It projects onto hyperbolas” doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: If you multiply the second and third equations together you get $bc(a+d-1)^2$. This is satisfied by *all* $b$ and $c$ since you’re assuming that $a=1-d$. Multiplying the two equations together produces no additional constraints since they’re already equivalent to $0=0$.

Comment: @amd Good catch, I made that way more difficult than it had to be.